# Equation solving with Haskell

Tags: haskell, math, functional-programming, list-comprehension, equation

I want to find all numbers up to N in Haskell, that satisfies the equation (Fermat theorem):

[image]

Some solutions could be:

[image]

So I try to do it like so in Haskell:

```
main :: IO ()
main =  do
    let arr = [ z * z == x * x + y * y | x <- [1..13], y <- [1..13], z <- [1..13]] in print arr
```

I get bool values list:

```
[False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,...]
```

There are 4 True values in total in that list. My questons are:

1. How do I get all tuples (x, y, z) that satisfies the given equation?
2. How can I count True values in that array?

UPDATE:
One more question. How can I count how many numbers do not belong to ANY tuple? I thought it would logically go like this:

```
solutions2 = [
    (z)
  | x <- [1..13]
  , y <- [x..13]
  , z <- [y..13]
  , z * z /= x * x + y * y, 
  z * z /= x * x - y * y, 
  z * z /= y * y - x * x
  ]
```

But that returned way too many numbers. Any ideas about how to find numbers that do not belong to any triples?

UPDATE2:
I have been experimenting and diging more. How can I pass number n, that I read from input to a previously efined function (calculation method)? I would like to be able to get solution array, print it and its lenght.

```
sol n = solution = [
    (x, y, z)
  | x <- [1..n]
  , y <- [x..n]
  , z <- [y..n]
  , z * z == x * x + y * y
  ]

main :: IO ()
main = do 
    putStrLn "Enter n:"
    n <- getLine
    let mySol = sol n
    print (mySol)
```

But i gives me error:

```
error: parse error on input `='
```

and also:

```
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Comment: just a few remarks: 1. Your examples seems to exclude duplicates (3,4,5) / (4,3,5) - you can do this by having `x <- [1..13], y <- [x..13]` (you get an order also) # 2. similarly `z` has to be at least as big as `y` (and `x`) so you could change to `z <- [y..13]` as well - it's a slight performance improvement and does not really matter for 13 but it will for 13 million ;)

Comment: Could you please also take a look at second update? @Carsten

Comment: the problem is in the line `sol n = solution = [` just change it to `sol n = [` - please note that you should not update the one question with more questions - that's not how StackOverflow works - you should ask new questions instead

Comment: please also note that you'll get yet another error on the line `let mySol = sol n` (most likely) as `getLine` reads in a `String` but you need an `Int` - try [`readLn`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:readLn) instead of `getLine`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work with a filter and yield an `(x, y, z)` tuple in case the filter is satisfied:

```
solutions = [
    (x, y, z)
  | x <- [1..13]
  , y <- [1..13]
  , z <- [1..13]
  , z * z == x * x + y * y
  ]

main :: IO ()
main =  do
    print solutions
```

This gives us the six solutions:

```
Prelude> solutions 
[(3,4,5),(4,3,5),(5,12,13),(6,8,10),(8,6,10),(12,5,13)]
```

You can also print `print (length solutions)` to obtain the number of solutions.

Comment: Thank you, it helped. But can I somehow filter out repeated solutions? I mean so that instead of (3,4,5) AND (4,3,5) I would get just one of them?

Comment: see my remark to your question - this can be easily done by changing the iteration

Comment: @vytaute: you can let `y` enumerate only `[1 .. x]`, this is more efficient and als means that `y <= x` and thus deduplicating the results.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Would you be so kind and also take a look to question update, I have one additional question :)

Comment: @vytaute: you can obtain a list of values in the tuples with `vals = [xi | (x, y, z) <- solutions, xi <- [x, y, z]]`, and then calculate the number of elements with ``length (filter (`notElem` vals) [1 .. 13])``

Comment: Thank you all for such a big help, you truly saved my day!

Comment: One more problem has arrisen. If you have time, please take a look. Thank you once again! @WillemVanOnsem